# Get a Usercontrol from a specific cell/column from grid

Tags: .net, wpf, web-applications, casting, grid

I have a grid withcolumns=3 and rows = 5. Each cell contains the same custom user control created at runtime. Each custom user control have a name and others properties differents.

So far so good....

When I try to get the object inside an specific cell I used (vb.net and WPF) this code:

```
Dim currentContainer As ObjectContainerControl = ContainerGrid.Children.Cast(Of UIElement)().OfType(Of ObjectContainerControl)().Where(Function(c) Grid.GetRow(c) = 0 And Grid.GetColumn(c) = 0)
```

Where `ObjectContainerControl` is my custom user control and container Grid is my grid'sname

This line send me the following error:

Unable to cast object of type `WhereEnumerableIterator'1[MyProject.ObjectContainerControl]` to type `My.ObjectContainerControl`.

How can i fix this???

Answer (score 0):

You need to select an element from the IEnumerable you get in your current query.

Call the First method as the last step in your query, to get the right element.

```
Dim currentContainer As ObjectContainerControl = 
    ContainerGrid.Children.Cast(Of UIElement)().OfType(Of ObjectContainerControl)()
    .Where(Function(c) Grid.GetRow(c) = 0 And Grid.GetColumn(c) = 0).**First()**
```